# How can I implement a JQuery or CSS3 responsive side menu that pushes the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, responsive-design

Ok, so I'm looking to implement a responsive side menu for my website using JQuery or CSS3. I have been looking for a side menu that will push the page content when the menu link is clicked. When the menu link is clicked, I am looking to add a X(close button) to the menu. I have had a look at some of the responsive menu's out there but can't seem to find one that will do what I am asking.

I have however found a website on themeforest that has exactly what I'm looking for. Can someone help me by explaining what plugin they have used, where to find it and also how they achieved this outcome.

[This is the website that has the responsive menu I am looking for. They have implemented it well](http://owwwlab.com/toranj/home-3.html)

Sorry I just realized I am asking exactly how this is done. I am really only looking for a JQuery plugin or an alternative that will accomplish the outcome in the above link. (owwwlab.com)

Comment: have you looked at what plugins the site you've linked to are using?

Comment: I have yes. I can't seem to narrow it down. They are all linked to the menu somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don know why you need a plugin for that while you just need a one function in jquery

```
.toggleClass()
```

that's it  and a little bit css expert .. see this

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls7osroc/4/)

its very simple to implement that yourself .. give it a try .. hope it help

Comment: This might make you laugh but I have copied the files word for word and it doesn't work. It works fine in Jsfiddle though.

Comment: So I managed to get this working, but there is one slight problem. Whenever I add links (my navigation) to the sidebar, I can't seem to click them. Can anyone help me with an updated version of the jsfiddle above?

Comment: @niven300 just remove  z-index: -1 from menuBar and make a wrapper position: relative; and sideBar z-index: 998;

Comment: @niven300 http://jsfiddle.net/Ls7osroc/8/  if you got any problem with Anchor  make it display:block; so you can control it well in css

Answer (score 0):

On the site you refer to the icon to trigger the menu has an id of 'menu-toggle-wrapper'.

If you search their custom js @ http://owwwlab.com/toranj/assets/js/custom.js you will find the function that fires when this button is clicked. You'll also have to dissect their CSS to figure out all the details of how the transitions work, because this behaviour is governed partly by this javascript trigger and partly by the site CSS.

Option B is to search for some jQuery off canvas menu plugins. This might be an easier route.

Good luck!